# A slice of type struct access index out of range

Tags: go

I am trying to use slice of type struct. Look at the following sample

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    arr := []struct {
        A string
        B string
    } {}

    arr[0].A = "I am"
    arr[0].B = "First"

    arr[1].A = "I am"
    arr[1].B = "Second"

    fmt.Println(arr)

}
```

When I compile this code I've got out of range error. Why?

Comment: Do the [tour](http://tour.golang.org). Which really should be mentioned more often on basic knowledge questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append new elements to your slice (if you don't make an array as in [FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25106397/6309).
It is easier with a named type instead of a type literal.

See "[Appending to and copying slices](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices)" and "[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)".

Example [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/vQHwqcPE1f)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type T struct {
        A string
        B string
    }

    arr := []T{}

    arr = append(arr, T{A: "I am", B: "First"})
    arr = append(arr, T{A: "I am", B: "Second"})

    fmt.Println(arr)
}
```

Output:

```
[{I am First} {I am Second}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created a slice with 0 (zero) elements. Access to elements at indices `0` and `1` is invalid. You probably wanted something like this:

```
arr := make([]struct{ A, B string }, 2)
```

Go slices do not automatically expand themselves to make room for more entries.